# Options for table with DataTables fo add, delete, resize and change order for columns

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datatables

Cay you help me, please?
I have a table use (DataTable plugin) (does not matter with what content) and  I need to be able to do some actions on the columns:

- **Have option to change columns place by dragging column left and right**
- **Add/delete new column** (all data for tabel is in angular object, and already available in page)
- **Have option resize columns**

And all of that options should be saved after page refresh.

A already try plug-in for DataTables [ColReorderWithResize.js](http://legacy.datatables.net/extras/thirdparty/ColReorderWithResize/) - but it doesn't saved state after refresh and it no option for add/delete column.

Maybe, someone know som plugin or couple for solve all of that my demands for table. Or some way for do it?
Thank you.

Comment: You can store/restore `ColReorderWithResize.js` status by using `stateSaveParams` etc, If you create all columns once you can have your own "add/delete column" by  `column.visible ` true/false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, [Datatables.js](https://datatables.net/) does all of that. The link to which you refer is old. The current reorder plugin is [here](https://datatables.net/extensions/colreorder/) and it will state save but you have to configure [state saving](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/state_save.html) correctly when the table is initialized.

Adding and removing columns can be set up with a [button](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/column_visibility/simple.html) and there are a couple of ways to resize columns, including an [initialization option](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.width).

Comment: `ColReorder` does not have a resize feature.  You cannot resize by using `column.width`

Comment: Didn't say you could resize with column.width. Said it was an initialization option.

Comment: @JoeMcCarty Thanks you. I pluged it, and almost implement all what I need. There is some bugs, but I think I'll fix it.